# UVa Online Judge 100th (3n+1) uDebug shows everything as correct but wrong answer

Tags: java

This is my first UVa submission so I had a few problems in the way. The biggest hurdle that took my time so far was probably getting all the formats correctly (I know, shouldn't have been too hard but I kept getting runtime error without knowing what that actually meant in this context). I did finally get past that runtime error, but I still get "Wrong answer."

Listed below are the things I've done for this problem. I've been working on this for the last few hours, and I honestly thought about just dropping it altogether, but this will bother me so much, so this is my last hope.

Things I've done:

- considered `int` overflow so changed to `long` at applicable places
- got the whole list (1-1000000) in the beginning through memorization for computation time
- submitted to uDebug. Critical input and Random input both show matching output.
- submitted to to UVa online judge and got "Wrong Answer" with 0.13~0.15 runtime.

Things I'm not too sure about:

- I think I read that UVa doesn't want its classes to be `public`. So I left mine as `class Main` instead of the usual `public class Main`. Someone from another place mentioned that it should be the latter. Not sure which one UVa online judge likes.
- input. I used `BufferedReader(new InputStreaReader (System.in))` for this. Also not sure if UVa online judge likes this.
- I thought my algorithm was correct but because of "Wrong answer," I'm not so sure. If my code is hard to read, I'll try to describe what I did after the code.

Here is my code:

```
class Main {

    public static int mainMethod(long i, int c, List<Integer> l) {
        if (i==1)
            return ++c;
        else if (i%2==0) {
            if (i<1000000&&l.get((int)i)!=null)
                return l.get((int)i)+c;
            else {
                c++;
                return mainMethod(i/2, c, l);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (i<1000000&&l.get((int)i)!=null)
                return l.get((int)i)+c;
            else {
                c++;
                return mainMethod(i*3+1, c, l);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int countMax(int x, int y, List<Integer> l) {
        int max=0;
        if (x>y) {
            int temp = x;
            x= y;
            y = temp;

        }
        for (int i=x; i<=y; i++) {
            if (l.get(i)>max)
                max = l.get(i);
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> fixed = Arrays.asList(new Integer[1000000]);

        for (long i=1; i<1000000; i++) {
            fixed.set((int)i, mainMethod(i,0,fixed));
        }
        String s;
        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while ((s = br.readLine())!=null) {
                int x = -1;
                int y = -1;
                for (String split : s.split("\\s+")) {
                    if (!split.equals("\\s+") && x==-1) {
                        x = Integer.parseInt(split);
                    } else if (!split.equals("\\s+") && x!=-1) {
                        y = Integer.parseInt(split);
                    }
                }
                if (x!=-1&&y!=-1)
                    System.out.println(Integer.toString(x) + " " + Integer.toString(y) + " " + Integer.toString(countMax(x,y,fixed)));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }


    }

}
```

I apologize for generic names for methods and variables. `mainMethod` deals with memorization and creating the initial list. `countMax` deals with the input from the problem (15 20) and finding the max length using the list. The for loop within the main method deals with potential empty lines and too many spaces.

So my (if not so obvious) question is, what is wrong with my code? Again, this worked perfectly fine on uDebug's Random Input and Critical Input. For some reason, however, UVa online judge says that it's wrong. I'm just clueless as to where it is. I'm a student so I'm still learning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't spotted your error yet, but a few things that may make it easier to spot.

First off:

int goes to 2^31, so declaring i in mainMethod to be long is unnecessary.  It also states in the problem specification that no operation will overflow an int, doesn't it?  Getting rid of the extraneous longs (and (int) casts) would make it easier to comprehend.

Second:

It's probably clearer to make your recursive call with c + 1 than ++c or doing c++ before it.   Those have side effects, and it makes it harder to follow what you're doing (because if you're incrementing c, there must be a reason, right?)  What you're writing is technically correct, but it's unidiomatic enough that it distracts.

Third:

So, am I missing something, or are you never actually setting any of the values in the List in your memoization function?  If I'm not blind (which is a possibility) that would certainly keep it from passing as-is.  Wait, no, definitely blind - you're doing it in the loop that calls it.  With this sort of function, I'd expect it to mutate the List in the function.  When you call it for i=1, you're computing i=4 (3 * 1 + 1) - you may as well save it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! 1. Although the question did explicitly say that int should work, when I actually first did the problem, I got an error around 130000 or so. When I checked, a lot of people were getting the same error at that number due to int overflow. This might be because I'm not doing the math efficiently (for example, instead of 3n+1, I could do (3n+1)/2 because 3n+1 will be even). 2. Thanks for the tip! I'll take note and apply that change 3. I think you're looking for the "fixed.set((int)i, mainMethod(i,0,fixed));" part inside Main.

Comment: I've applied your suggestion (my code looks something like return mainMethod(i*3+1, c+1, l); instead of having c++ above). I checked the output again just in case I made a mistake while editing. Output was fine (checked with uDebug again). I submitted, but still "Wrong Answer" with similar runtime. unfortunate.